# iOS - loading items when user reach the scroll view bottom

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift3, cloudkit

I'm currently using CloudKit as my backend and so far I've been enjoying it pretty much.

I've a query happening, that retrieves data to populate a table view.

Since I don't know the items count that it may have, I'm filtering the query to X number of items (let's say 15).

My goal is that when the user scrolls down to the bottom (last queried item) of the table view  ill query the backend to continue filling the table view.

I've searched but couldn't find CloudKit code that does this.

Can somebody give me a hint on how to do it?

Thank you all for the given help. 
Best, Ivan.

Comment: Why note use `uitableview`? You can search and get many results with key: "UITableView load more"

Comment: I've miss write the question I'm not using scroll view I'm using tableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On IOS I think you have to use UITableViewController or just UITableView.

Add a UIActivityIndicatorView (i.e. spinner) to your UITableViewController. Connect the outlet to the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!
```

Add a property to your UITableViewController to keep track that you're currently loading more data so that you don't try to do it twice:

```
var loadingData = false
```

Start the spinner animating and then call refreshRes():

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
if !loadingData && indexPath.row == refreshPage - 1 {
    spinner.startAnimating()
    loadingData = true
    refreshRes()
}
```

Have refreshRes() run on a background thread. This will allow your table to still move freely. The animated spinner will tell the user that more data is coming. Once your query returns, update the table data on the main thread.

```
func refreshRes() {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
    // this runs on the background queue
    // here the query starts to add new 15 rows of data to arrays

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // this runs on the main queue
        self.refreshPage += 15
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.spinner.stopAnimating()
        self.loadingData = false
    }
}
```

After that it's depend of the server result you have to make a request to GET the others 15 datas

Comment: Thanks that great.

Comment: @G Clovs I'm wondering how are you using the refreshPage property? Do I need a specific delegate?

Comment: I got it. The refreshPage is the current item tracker retrieved